# Resolving userID Field Error in Angular Vehicle Registration Form

Tags: angular, authentication, error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlySC.png)
I develop a vehicle valuation system from angular. In this system, there is a vehicle registration. It should be done only by Valuar and Data Collector only. After logging into the system, they can access the vehicle registration form. As shown below, there is an error occurring. How I solve this error? In the vehicle registration form, there is no field for userID. It comes from when the user logging.

I have tried to get userID from the JWT token and decode it. But didn't succeed it.I expect here to solve this error and send data to the backend without any errors.